# importing a 3d model from spline to three.js

Tags: three.js, 3d, spline, 3d-model

I want to know if I can import a 3d model from spline to a three js project. If yes, how can I do it? I want to create a 3d model and include it in three js as a geo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, you can export it as `.gltf` in spline:

[image: Spline export]

and then import it in three.js like this:

```js
//import the loader from cdn or directly from three package
//import { GLTFLoader } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.126.0/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

// Instantiate it
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()

//Load it
gltfLoader.load(
    'path of your model .gltf',
    (gltf) =>
    {
      //add it to the scene
        scene.add(gltf.scene.children[0])
    }
)
```